# Mysql get all rows but join if possible

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a problem with my Mysql query. I am trying to join two tables on a shared value and grab data from the joined table. The issue is that even when there isn't a matching value in both tables I still want to pull the data from the first table.

For example, if I have two tables like below:

```
contact_id   first_name   last_name
-----------------------------------
1            Bob          Smith
2            George       McDonald
3            Joe          Blo

contact_id   note
-------------------------------
1            hello
3            test
```

Here is my query:

```
$this->db->select('center_contacts.contact_id, first_name, last_name, GROUP_CONCAT(center_contacts_notes.note) as notes');
$this->db->from('center_contacts');
$this->db->join('center_contacts_notes', 'center_contacts_notes.contact_id = center_contacts.contact_id');
$this->db->group_by('center_contacts.id');
```

The results from my query **should** look something like:

```
Array
(
    [contact_id] => 1
    [first_name] => Bob
    [last_name] => Smith
    [note] => hello
)
Array
(
    [contact_id] => 2
    [first_name] => George
    [last_name] => McDonald
)
Array
(
    [contact_id] => 3
    [first_name] => Joe
    [last_name] => Blo
    [note] => test
)
```

Instead my results do not include the second array for george. He is not in the output because he is not able to be joined on my second table. How can I solve this? Sould I use UNION or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear you cant have result with different number of columns. So all your result will have `[note]`  but the one without data will be null.

Comment: So I need a left join or I need aliases?

Comment: You need a LEFT JOIN. You may also require aliases.

Comment: Beautiful. I knew it had to be that easy. Thanks.